# Generate javadoc of a project using Play framework 2.3

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a java application using Play framework 2.3.8.

I have read about the old commands such as `play doc`.

After running `activator doc`, I get a jar named `***-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar` in `target\scala-2.11` directory. But it is empty.

Could anyone point out by how I could generate the HTML javadoc automatically?

---

Base on @turutosiya answer, below is what I have done.

`Scaladoc` will generate by command `activator doc`. However, if you would like `javadoc`, please add `sources in (Compile, doc) ~= (_ filter (_.getName endsWith ".java"))` in your `build.sbt`. This will force `sbt` to generate the `javadoc` style api documentation.

However, as for me who want `javadoc` but do not want it to be in my zip package generated by `activator dist`. I add the following line to my distribution script.

```
zip --delete target/universal/*.zip application_name-\*/share/\*
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After typing  `activator doc` or `sbt doc`, you can find the documents under :

```
target/scala-2.11/api
```

Comment: there is no directory named `target/api`. but could you tell me if there are any possible configuration / settings that might prevent activator from generating docs?

Comment: well I'm not sure about the details. just fyi, my stack : jdk 1.8.0_45, scala 2.11.6, sbt 0.13.8, play framework 2.3.8

Comment: Did you install any sbt plugins for generating the Javadoc, and what's your command for achieving that?

Comment: I've never install additional plugin the javadoc generation. and just typing `activator doc`

Comment: Thanks @turutosiya now I can generate scaladoc by `activator doc` in `target/scala-2.11/api`. But activator can generate javadoc for you in `target/api` is that true?

Comment: @XinziZhou yes true. I think that's because I've set `crossPaths := false` in my build.sbt.

Answer (score 0):

I generate JavaDoc with the following command:

```
play javadoc
```